# Getting SIGSEGV in NOP-Slide

Tags: c, gdb, reverse-engineering

[image]

I am trying to return from main into an NOP-Slide but I get a SIGSEGV when the program returns to the first NOP operation.
Am I am getting something wrong here? Can't see the problem...

Comment: Maybe the page doesn't have execute permissions?

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: Sorry, that's as far as I can help you.

Answer (score 2):

> but I get a SIGSEGV when the program returns to the first NOP operation

It looks like your `NOP`s are on the stack.

The stack is not eXecutable by default, so `SIGSEGV` is expected. You can check whether your binary was built for non-executable stack like so:

```
readelf -Wl a.out | grep GNU_STACK
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000000 0x000000 RW  0x10
```

Note `RW` and not `RWE` permissions.

To build a program with executable stack, use `-Wl,-z,execstack` at link time.